# Log changes that occur into a separate log sheet only if the data hasn't been logged before

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Say I have a list with two Columns: UserID and LastLoginTime.

This list is populated and updated automatically using the IMPORTDATA() function directly in the spreadsheet.

Now, I'd like to create a log that checks every hour for all the changes that occur and copy them into a new sheet.
Every time the script runs, it should only log a new row if:

- It doesn't already have the UserID (new user).
- If the LastLoginTime changed for an existing user in the log.

I am currently able to log all rows every hour with the below method but I'm unsure how to check the above two conditions.

```
  function LogNeworUpdatedEntries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array
  
  var ss_log = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_log = ss_log.getSheetByName("Log_Sheet");
  var datarange_log = sheet_log.getDataRange();
  var lastrow_log = datarange_log.getLastRow();
  var values_log = datarange_log.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array  
  
  

  for (i=lastrow;i>=1;i--) {
  var UserID = values[i-1][1];
  var LastLoginTime = values[i-1][2];
  if (UserID!="")   //I'm struggling here. How do I search the existing values in the sheet_log?
  {
     sheet.getRange(i, 1,1,2).copyTo(sheet_log.getRange(lastrow_log+1,1,1,2));
     lastrow_log++;
  }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- From `Say I have a list with two Columns: UserID and LastLoginTime.` and `sheet.getRange(i, 1,1,2).copyTo(sheet_log.getRange(lastrow_log+1,1,1,2))`, in this case, I thought that "UserID" and "LastLoginTime" are put in the columns "A" and "B", respectively.
- When new "UserID" is added, you want to copy the row to the next empty row of "Log_Sheet".
- When "LastLoginTime" is changed, you want to copy the row to the next empty row of "Log_Sheet".

#### Modification points:

- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be declared one time.
- From `var UserID = values[i-1][1];` and `var LastLoginTime = values[i-1][2];`, if "UserID" and "LastLoginTime" are put in the columns "A" and "B", respectively, it's `var UserID = values[i-1][0];` and `var LastLoginTime = values[i-1][1];` because the 1st index is 0.
- In your situation, I think that it is required to check the values of "Log_Sheet". But `values_log` is not used.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function LogNeworUpdatedEntries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

  var sheet_log = ss.getSheetByName("Log_Sheet");
  var datarange_log = sheet_log.getDataRange();
  var lastrow_log = datarange_log.getLastRow();
  var values_log = datarange_log.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array  
  
  // Create an object for searching values of "Log_Sheet".
  var obj = values_log.reduce((o, [a, b]) => Object.assign(o, {[a]: b}));

  // Create an array of changed values in "Sheet1".
  var changedValues = values.filter(([a, b]) => !obj[a] || obj[a].getTime() != b.getTime());

  // Append the array to "Log_Sheet".
  if (changedValues.length > 0) {
    sheet_log.getRange(lastrow_log + 1, 1, changedValues.length, changedValues[0].length).setValues(changedValues);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of "LastLoginTime" are the date object. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you for the great write-up.
Yes, I did have to convert to a date object using new Date(b).getTime() and also use values.shift() to remove the header row.

Comment: @Victor -------- Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.